# Strange Behaviour in Tibco BE 5.0..help needed

Tags: tibco

I am new to Tibco Business Events and facing a strange issue in BE 5.0. This is what I am trying to do:
I have created a DB concept named INVENTORYCONCEPT and have created a corresponding event for the same.
I have set this event as default destination in my JMS channel. Now when I am trying to create the instance of INVENTORYCONCEPT by giving command like ‘Concepts.INVENTORYCONCEPT inventory’ the BE studio gives me error that “INVENTORYCONCEPT is not the part of Concept folder” .
PFA the screenshot of my project files.
So can anyone tell me that what I have missed here ?

PS: I tried the traditional methods of restarting thr studio and changing the workspace.

[image]

Comment: can you share how you resolved the issue in an answer?

Answer (score 2):

You need to give some name to the concept instance that you are creating. What you are doing right now is

```
Concepts.INVENTORYCONCEPT = null;
```

This is wrong. You need to do something like this

```
Concepts.INVENTORYCONCEPT inventory = null;
```

Its always recommended & advised that you clean and validate your project when any changes are made to the project.

If the error still persists, you can open the concept using XML Viewer in BE and check the relative path of the Concept there. The reason for this to happen is when you create a concept in a some folder and later move it to a different folder, sometimes the XML related to that concept doesn't change (usually when you drag and drop the .concept file instead of using the Refactor option). You can just change the relative path in the XML and it should work.

Sometimes weird errors also occur when your workspace gets corrupted. In such cases, changing the default workspace and importing the project in the new workspace does the job.